# force desktop firefox to reflow text/content?

Tags: firefox

Due to poor eyesight I usually zoom-in pages to a huge amount. Due to multi-tasking I usually snap desktop FireFox to one side of the screen, and something else to the other side (win7 onwards "desktop snap" feature, not win8 modern app snapping).

On some websites and forums, especially those without a mobile version available, I have to then deal with scrolling left and right in order to read a full line of text.

Is there a way to force all websites to reflow their text/content in general, when the FireFox window isn't maximized? This way the content/text would reflow onto the next line so that I don't have to horizontal scroll all the time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar need, and frustration.

I found using the "Enter Reader View" mode in Firefox (book icon to the right of the URL) met this need. It stripped away banners, images and navigation but did present the text in clear, resizeable and reflowable form.

Answer (score 0):

There are some "bookmarklets" that might be of help. They can remove unnecessary images, "linearize" (reflow) the text, etc.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet and http://www.bookmarklets.com/ for some info.
Bookmarklets do not require installation and are just little pieces of javascript. Some might not work in a particular browser, but they're easy to download and to try. *Linearize* might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Google Mobilizer is a web service that can be used to view just the text and optionally images within web pages.

I built a [Google Mobilizer Bookmarklet](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2012/04/google-mobilizer-bookmarklet-view-just.html) so that it can work with any web page. To use the bookmarklet, drag & drop the [bookmarklet](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2012/04/google-mobilizer-bookmarklet-view-just.html) to your browser's Bookmark/Favorites bar. While you're on a web page whose content you wish to "linearize"/reflow the text of, click on the bookmarklet & it will then redirect the URL of the currently open web page to the Google Mobilizer web service which processes it to show just the text and optionally images within web pages.